# Canvas, scrolling and special use case in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, scroll, canvas

I have a canvas of variable width and height with a maximum being **2K*2K**

This canvas current height and width vary depending on the user screen size. Usualy smaller than 2K*2K.

If the user moves an element (free moving elements like child UIcontainer) inside the canvas at position greater than the current user available H and W, scrollbars should appears (they do and that's fine).

But how can I limit the scrolling  ?

Is there a way to give a max to the vscrolling and hscrolling ? Should i create my own policy ?

Thanks.

Comment: are you trying to constrain the draggability of the elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe put a canvas inside another canvas and set it to 100% width and height to fill the outer canvas and give the inner canvas a max height and width. Not sure if that will work, not 100% sure I understand your problem either but its the only thing that popped into my head right now.